# Visual Studio generates 64 errors per custom form for a list

Tags: error, custom-form, visual-studio-2012

While creating a List Custom Form for Shareppoint 2013, Visual Studio 2012 generates 64 errors, *(as visualized below)* for every custom form added to the solution.

The deployment just works fine as well as the form itself.

The lines which are causing the Errors are those, which are included at the beginning of the aspx file. Without those lines, the Deployment works fine, but not the form itself.

```
<%@ Page language="C#" MasterPageFile="~masterurl/default.master"    Inherits="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.WebPartPage,Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c"  %>
<%@ Register Tagprefix="SharePoint" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebControls" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="Utilities" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Import Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint" %> <%@ Assembly Name="Microsoft.Web.CommandUI, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %> <%@ Register Tagprefix="WebPartPages" Namespace="Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages" Assembly="Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=15.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c" %>
```

**Question:**
   How to get rid of these?

[image]